Can't stream two rtmp streams simultaneously on nginx server
I'm having a problem streaming two streams at the same time using nginx/1.22.1 and ffmpeg on raspberrypi 6.6.20+rpt-rpi-v8 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.6.20-1+rpt1 (2024-03-07) aarch64 GNU/Linux
nginx.conf
rtmp {
        server {
                listen 1935;
                chunk_size 4096;
                application live {
                        live on;
                        record off;
                        exec_play /home/pi/ffmpeg_live.sh &;
                }
                application live1 {
                        live on;
                        record off;
                        exec_play /home/pi/ffmpeg_live1.sh &;
                }
        }
}

ffmpeg_live.sh (ffmpeg_live1.sh is pretty much the same with different lock and rtmp url)
#!/bin/bash
lock_file=/tmp/.rtmp_lock
if test -f $lock_file; then
 exit 1
else
 touch $lock_file
fi

#
#... code that retrieves v.mp4 and a.m4a (forks with '&')
#
/home/pi/ffmpeg-3.4.2-arm64-64bit-static/ffmpeg -y -loglevel info -fflags +genpts   -re -i "v.mp4" -i "a.m4a"  -map 0  -map 1  -strict unofficial  -metadata date="2024-04-25T19:50:28.9104087+01:00" -ignore_unknown -copy_unknown -c copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/stream & #forks!

rm -rf $lock_file

I'm using exec_play so the stream will start only when I'm connecting to the rtmp server, and lock file to prevent that ffmpeg will be executed multiple times if the rtmp url is requested more than once.
If I'm accessing only one of the streams everything works fine, however when I'm accessing one stream and then accessing the other stream, sometime it works and I can see the stream from a remote player but most of the time both streams will fail to stream even though ffmpeg is still running, after some time one of them might stream again.
Any suggestions how to fix it?
Thanks.
Update:
I'm trying to pinpoint the problem so I've used only one stream in the conf (application live1 only):
On the first try I'm trying to stream after service nginx restart, it won't stream but it will stream in the second try after I kill the first ffmpeg process:
$ service nginx restart
*SENDING PLAY*
*FFMPEG STARTED* (exec_play)
*NO STREAM RECEIVED*
$ killall -9 ffmpeg
*SENDING PLAY*
*FFMPEG STARTED* (exec_play)
*STREAM WORKS*

nginx access.log
192.168.1.16 [29/Apr/2024:22:21:38 +0100] PLAY "live1" "stream" "" - 351 542 "" "" (10s)
192.168.1.16 [29/Apr/2024:22:21:48 +0100] PLAY "live1" "stream" "" - 351 542 "" "" (10s)
192.168.1.16 [29/Apr/2024:22:21:59 +0100] PLAY "live1" "stream" "" - 351 542 "" "" (10s)
192.168.1.16 [29/Apr/2024:22:22:12 +0100] PLAY "live1" "stream" "" - 351 542 "" "" (10s)
127.0.0.1 [29/Apr/2024:22:22:24 +0100] PUBLISH "live1" "stream" "" - 16349560 409 "" "FMLE/3.0 (compatible; Lavf59.27" (49s)
192.168.1.16 [29/Apr/2024:22:23:13 +0100] PLAY "live1" "stream" "" - 443 9115389 "" "" (34s)

second PUBLISH is not shown on the log, I think because it prints after ending the stream.
I figured that the problem comes from exec_play because when I comment exec_play and runffmpeg_live1.sh script after restarting nginx it streams on the first try.
My final goal is to start a script (with ffmpeg) when client connects (PLAY) and kill the script when the last client disconnects (i also tried exec_pull but it has similar problem as exec_play), I'm using a script and not ffmpeg directly because the script runs a code the retrieves the video/audio.
